# Can we add JitsiMeetView to our custom layout?

Tags: android, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I need to add JitsiMeetView to my custom layout for a video application. Is it possible ?

Here I used - 
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.2.2') { transitive = true }

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        view = new JitsiMeetView(MainActivity.this);
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                .setRoom("https://meet.jit.si/456")
                .setAudioMuted(false)
                .setVideoMuted(false)
                .setAudioOnly(false)
                .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                .build();
        view.join(options);

        videoView.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: I tried in the above way you are doing but the layout is fluctuating. and camera is not able to focus, it keeps on fluctuating.

Comment: I have solved it using framelayout, please see my answer below.

Comment: Hey @Saneesh M S Did you resolved It. I am also Stuck. Please reply if solved

Answer (score 4):

For perfect results, change RelativeLayout to Framelayout and put fixed width or height while adding the View.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    view = new JitsiMeetView(MainActivity.this);
    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
            .setRoom("https://meet.jit.si/456")
            .setAudioMuted(false)
            .setVideoMuted(false)
            .setAudioOnly(false)
            .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
            .build();
    view.join(options);

    videoView.addView(view, 500, 1000);
}
```